# HTML Checkboxes, how to load with an xml page?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have checkboxes that I need to load on two separate xml pages. I have them in the HTML however I cant figure out how to confine them to only appearing on the separate xml pages

JAVASCRIPT

```
function init()
{

 document.getElementById('one').onclick = function(){ getData('shop1.xml'); }
 document.getElementById('two').onclick = function(){ getData('shop2.xml'); }
}


function checkbox()
{
document.getElementById('checkbox').onload = function(){          getData('checkbox');}
}
 window.onload = init;


HTML
 <input type = "checkbox"> <span> 1</span>
 <input type = "checkbox"> <span> 2</span>
 <input type = "checkbox"> <span> 3</span>
```

Comment: wahat is the `getData` function doing? What are the elements with ids `one` an `two`? And the function `checkbox()` is trying to get an element with id `checkbox`, which does not exist in the HTML you provided.